# Uncaught TypeError: I cannot set value of score in Memory game

Tags: javascript

This code should give me a score if I clicked on two or more images in the memory game but, instead, it is giving me an error. It's showing the error message

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
> at checkMatch

I think the error might be caused due to typo but when I searched for the typo there was not any. I searched on Stack Overflow but I can't find any solution that's why posting here.

Below is the screenshot of the given programme.

[image]

javascript code below

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const cardArray = [{
      name: 'fries',
      img: 'images/fries.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'cheeseburger',
      img: 'images/cheeseburger.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'ice-cream',
      img: 'images/ice-cream.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'pizza',
      img: 'images/pizza.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'milkshake',
      img: 'images/milkshake.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'hotdog',
      img: 'images/hotdog.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'fries',
      img: 'images/fries.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'cheeseburger',
      img: 'images/cheeseburger.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'ice-cream',
      img: 'images/ice-cream.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'pizza',
      img: 'images/pizza.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'milkshake',
      img: 'images/milkshake.png'
    },
    {
      name: 'hotdog',
      img: 'images/hotdog.png'
    }
  ]
  console.log(cardArray);

  cardArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())

  const gridDisplay = document.querySelector('#grid')
  const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('#result')


  function createBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
      const card = document.createElement('img');
      card.setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png');
      card.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
      card.setAttribute('data-id', i);
      console.log(card, i)
      gridDisplay.appendChild(card)
    }
  }
  let cardsChosen = [];
  const cardsWon = [];
  let cardsChosenIds = []

  function checkMatch() {
    const card = document.querySelectorAll('img')
    const optionOneId = cardsChosenIds[0]
    const optionTwoId = cardsChosenIds[1]

    if (optionOneId == optionTwoId) {
      card[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png');
      card[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png');
      alert("you selected same card twice");
    } else if (cardsChosen[0] === cardsChosen[1]) {
      alert('You found a match')
      card[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/white.png')
      card[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'images/white.png')
      card[optionOneId].removeEventListener('click', flipCard)
      card[optionTwoId].removeEventListener('click', flipCard)
      cardsWon.push(cardsChosen)
    } else {
      card[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png');
      card[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png');
      alert("you selected different card. Try Again! ");
    }
    cardsChosen = []
    cardsChosenIds =[]
      resultDisplay.innerHTML= cardsWon.length
  if(cardsWon.length ==(cardArray.length/2)){
  resultDisplay.innerHTML = 'Congralutions you won it all'
  }
  }

  function flipCard() {
    let getid = this.getAttribute('data-id')
    cardsChosen.push(cardArray[getid].name)
    cardsChosenIds.push(getid)
    console.log(cardsChosen)
    console.log(cardsChosenIds);
    this.setAttribute('src', cardArray[getid].img)
    if (cardsChosen.length == 2) {
      setTimeout(checkMatch, 1100)
    }

  }
  createBoard()
})
```

This is html code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Memory Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Score : <span id ="result"></span></h3>

    <div id = "grid"> </div>
    <script script src= "neck.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```js
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('#result')
```

to

```js
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result')
```

Because you are already getting the ID with a special method, you don't need the `#` sign.